# How to delete old backup jobs on Azure

Tags: python, azure, sdk, backup

I am new to Azure and the Azure Python SDK, and I have some questions.

How do I delete old backups of a VM using Python SDK? I have looked it up on Azure CLI documentation but have not found the delete command.

I am thinking of modifying the retention policy within the policy associated with the backups. Will changing the retention policy delete old backups?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below Powershell cmdlet to Delete the backup item as mentioned in the Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/soft-delete-virtual-machines#delete-the-backup-item-using-azure-powershell):

```
Disable-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtection -Item $myBkpItem -RemoveRecoveryPoints -VaultId $myVaultID -Force
```

You can also **Delete backup data of a VM** using the Azure portal by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/soft-delete-virtual-machines#soft-delete-for-vms-using-azure-portal).

> Will changing the retention policy delete old backups?

Refer this to know about [modifing the retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-vm-backup-faq#manage-vm-backups).